# How would the filament tube of a typical incandescent lightbulb shatter without the filament burning out?

Tags: electrical, lighting

Several lightbulbs in my friend's old, brownstone NYC apartment have been going out in a strange way. The filament looks perfectly fine, not burnt out, but the tube around it is shattered. Power surges / failing circuit breakers would have to burn out the filament, right? What could be causing this?

Comment: That is weird! Can you get us some closeups of the failed lightbulbs?

Comment: manufacturing defect in the tubes reducing their ability to handle heat would be my guess

Comment: Are you talking about incandescent lamps or fluorescent?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel - I'll see if I can get some from my friend, but he just went out of town.

Comment: @ArchonOSX - Incandescent. Regular 60W I'm guessing, or non-spiral energy savers.

Comment: Has anyone tried switching one of these broken globes on?

Comment: Closing the loop on this old question. Never got to look at the bulbs myself and lost touch with the friend. Thanks for all your interest in helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing that would fracture glass other than a defect would be a severe or extreme temperature change that would change the expansion of the glass unevenly. Look for dripping water or oil or something making contact with the lamp in a single area.

Good luck

Comment: +1 Water on a hot incandescent bulb will break it quite quickly.